# How can I change the texture position in DirectX 12

Tags: c++, position, direct3d, texture2d

I need to change the position of the texture in the window, I have it drawn in the upper left corner, and I want to place it in the center. In directx 11 we can do this

`m_deviceResources->GetD2DDeviceContext()->SetTransform(...)`, but I haven't found any similar code for directx 12. I don't understand how i can change the texture position, maybe I need to change something in ConstantBuffer or change the code for the shader.

Texture Code

```
void CreateTexture(int width, int height, const void* pData)
{
    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDesc = {};
    resourceDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    resourceDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    resourceDesc.Width = width;
    resourceDesc.Height = height;
    resourceDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
    resourceDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
    resourceDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    resourceDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    resourceDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

    D3D12MA::ALLOCATION_DESC allocationDesc = {};
    allocationDesc.HeapType = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    D3D12MA::Allocation* alloc = nullptr;
    allocator->CreateResource(
        &allocationDesc,
        &resourceDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE,
        nullptr,
        &alloc,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&OffscreenTexture));

    UpdateTextureResource(width, height, pData);

    // Describe and create a SRV for the texture.
    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {};
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.Format = resourceDesc.Format;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    Device->CreateShaderResourceView(OffscreenTexture, &srvDesc, OffscreenSrvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    alloc->Release();
}

void UpdateTextureResource(int width, int height, const void* pData)
{
    if (pData == nullptr) 
        return;

    if (upload_texture)
        upload_texture->Release();

    auto Barrier = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(OffscreenTexture, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST);
    CommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &Barrier);

    const UINT64 uploadBufferSize = GetRequiredIntermediateSize(OffscreenTexture, 0, 1);

    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC desc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(uploadBufferSize);

    D3D12MA::ALLOCATION_DESC allocationDesc = {};
    allocationDesc.HeapType = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD;
    allocator->CreateResource(
        &allocationDesc,
        &desc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
        NULL,
        &upload_texture,
        __uuidof(ID3D12Resource),
        nullptr);

    if (upload_texture == nullptr)
        return;

    D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA textureData = {};
    textureData.pData = pData;
    textureData.RowPitch = width * 4; // TextureWidth * TextureSize
    textureData.SlicePitch = textureData.RowPitch * height;

    UpdateSubresources(CommandList, OffscreenTexture, upload_texture->GetResource(), 0, 0, 1, &textureData);
    auto barrier = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(OffscreenTexture, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE);
    CommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
}
```

Shader Code

```
struct PSInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD;
};

Texture2D g_texture : register(t0);
SamplerState g_sampler : register(s0);

PSInput VSMain(float4 position : POSITION, float4 uv : TEXCOORD)
{
    PSInput result;

    result.position = position;
    result.uv = uv;

    return result;
}

float4 PSMain(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return g_texture.Sample(g_sampler, input.uv);
}
```

Comment: For dynamic texture animation, pass in the desired transform matrix (e.g. `float4x4 texTransform`) to the vertex shader via constant buffer, and calculate the new uv e.g. `result.uv = mul(float4(uv, 0, 1), texTransform).xy`. Also, you are using the `IID_PPV_ARGS` macro when creating the offscreen resource, so why are you then using `__uuidof` when creating the upload resource?

Comment: very thx for answer! I'll change __uuidof on IID_PPV_ARGS. But how can I change the position without shaders? I want to change the position at runtime process execution or by user data. Or can I somehow change the shader code during the runtime of the application? I'm new to dx 12, but I need to write a program

Comment: Vertex transformation in Direct3D 10, 11, and 12 is all done via HLSL programmable shaders.  Your reference to **SetTransform** is not Direct3D 11, but is actually Direct2D. BTW, depending on your needs, you may want to take a look at the **SpriteBatch** class in the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: yes I also found Directx12 and i'm already starting to study it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DirectXTK12 library helped me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).